# Win8 Request full login prompt from inside a Family Safety account

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

Setting up a new school laptop for my son.

**The Administrator account is still disabled** and I password-protected the user account with administrator permissions ("parent account"). I then created a user-level account with Family Safety turned on for the child.

Configured his account, then logged back in as parent (admin level) account. I then used this well-known reg hack to hide the parent account on the startup screen.

```
HKLM -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows NT -> WinLogon -> SpecialAccounts -> UserList
```

Oops.

Once I logged out as parent, how can I log back in again? The usual trick is to:

- type cmd at the start menu,
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>Right-click</kbd> on cmd.exe from the search list, and
- choose Run As Another Account from the pop-up context menu

However, that option no longer displays on the pop-up context menu! (*Maybe this is a new Win8 "feature", or maybe it's because it's a Family Safety account...?*)

Is there any way from a child account to force a login box or some other idea to login as a hidden account?

Please remember: I did not enable the Administrator account (disabled by default), so that option is not open to me.

---

**UPDATE:**

I found a way around the problem and had posted/accepted that as the correct answer. I removed the "correct answer" checkmark and would prefer a better answer. (*I so dislike accepting my own solutions.*)

**So, there *must* be a way to get a login prompt, from inside a Family Safety account, that allows one to specify both the user and password.**

Microsoft has been guilty of muddled thinking in the past, but never *this* muddled.

Therefore, the question remains open for a solution.

Comment: There are tools to enable the Administrator account I would use those the undo your hack

Comment: Sounds great. Where can I get those tools?

Comment: This is one of many tutorials http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/507-built-administrator-account-enable-disable.html I assume its possible to escalate a command because the parent account still exists

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out of this.

While logged into a restricted `Family Safety` child account (the only account we could log into because the account with Admin privs was now hidden from the login screen), I couldn't find a way to perform a system restore.

For those not already in the know, System Restore allows you to *turn the clock back* on your system files and restore the system to a previous time (without affecting the data). Fortunately, I was able to choose a restore point about an hour before my big error.

Frankly, I was very very surprised that a Family Safety account had access to do a system restore! (*So a savvy child can do a system restore and undo some parental changes..? As much as I prefer Microsoft over Apple, the Apple architects have done a much better job in this area.*)

At any rate, here is how to perform a system restore from a Family Safety account:

1. Use [one of these methods](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm) to open the Advanced Startup Options menu
2. Choose System Restore
3. Restore back to an earlier point

For myself, I found the Advanced Startup Options menu by:

- Swiping (lower right corner) to get the Charms Bar
- Settings
- Advanced Settings
- System Restore